# ionic2 background image not showing

Tags: ionic2

I want set background image in pages of ionic2,

```
  <style type="text/css">
    ion-content {
      background: url(../../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
  </style>
  <ion-content  padding>
      <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  </ion-content>
```

but it not showing in the device.
why?

Comment: Maybe your url is wrong. Try to change it to an image in the internet.

Comment: I have tried this method.

Comment: So, what is the result?

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: Maybe other element overlap your `ion-content` and you can not see the result. Delete all the content in `ion-content`. Set it `height` and `width` `100%`. Set `background-color: green`. Change `background-image url` to a live image. What is the result?

Comment: When i add "background-color: green" in the css, the background can become green. but i just want add an image.

Comment: Now, it must be one in two reasons: 1. Your url is wrong. 2. Your image is too small. Add: `background-size: 100% 100% !important`

Comment: yes, url is wrong, all images used in html files should be in src/assets/. thank you

Comment: where are you setting the css content? in the html file?

Comment: yes, in the html file

Comment: try setting in the corresponding scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your css for the `ion-content`:

```
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.content-md {
  background: url("../../img/background.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the picture into the assets/img folder. 
Then use the following code in your css:

```
background-image: url('../assets/img/background.jpg')
```

This is because Ionic will search for your images relative to your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the background to `.scroll-content` like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scroll-content {
      background: url(../../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
  </style>
  <ion-content  padding>
      <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been few monthes, but you can do it that way

```
<ion-content style="background-image: url('assets/images/background-image.jpg');">
    <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
</ion-content>
```